# Leaving only words that start with capital letter in R studio

Tags: r

I have an Excel with a column with lots of rows where i have entries like "1,942 European ancestry cases, 4,565 European ancestry controls". How can i eliminate everything except for the words that start with capital letter, so I´m just left with "European"

I tried using the function `filtered_vector <- str_subset(x, "^[[:upper:]]")` but it didnt work, neither did `gsub("\\b[a-z]+\\s+", "", x)`

Comment: Could you edit your question to provide some example data? What you have posted isn't exactly clear - for instance, is "1,942 European ancestry cases, 4,565 European ancestry controls" in the same cell in Excel, or are those two separate entries? What would happen if there are two capitalized words, would you want both? Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

This may not be robust enough for your larger dataset, but you can try `strsplit()` followed by `grep()`:

```
unique(grep("^[A-Z]", strsplit(s, " ")[[1]],value = T))
```

Output:

```
[1] "European"
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example, `x` is a character vector with only one element and this element does not start with an uppercase letter. Thus `str_subset()` discards this element. In order to make this work, you have to split the character string into multiple elements:

```r
library(stringr)

x <- c(
  "1,942 European ancestry cases, 4,565 European ancestry controls",
  "1532 Änd small"
)

x |> 
  str_split(boundary("word")) |>
  map(\(x) unique(str_subset(x, "^[[:upper:]]")))
#> Error in map(str_split(x, boundary("word")), function(x) unique(str_subset(x, : could not find function "map"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-12-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Collapse the results with `unique()` if necessary.

Note that your regex pattern `"^[[:upper:]]"` is actually more robust than something like `"^[A-Z]"` because it captures non-ASCII characters such as "Ä".

Comment: Good point, I adjusted the code.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is using `str_extract_all()`:

```
stringr::str_extract_all(x, "\\b[A-Z]\\w*") |> unique()
```

`\\b` is the start of a new word, `[A-Z]` is a capital letter, and `\\w*` looks for any number of letters after that.

Data:

```
x <- c("1,942 European ancestry cases", "4,565 European ancestry controls")
```